# Firebase token generation on react native, verify on Node

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a react native app using firebase for authentication. Before each outgoing request I call:

```
auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(token => {
```

I then make an outgoing request to my server with that token in the header. Then on my server I call:

```
firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
```

Which is then supposed to verify the token and the user that made the request. This workflow has been working for the past few months but today I have rebooted my remote server and each token that it tries to verify is expired. On the front end I tried doing a console.log of the token immediately after it is generated and it shows that the token was created and expires in 2019. I try logging in with various accounts and each token that is generated says that it is created at and expires in 2019, under claims it shows 1970. After 2-3 hours this issue went away, I was able to do everything successfully. I still did a console.log for my token and it still shows up as expired even though the firebase on my server accepts it as being verified. From being curious about what triggered this issue I rebooted my server and now all incoming tokens have expired again.

Here is what getTokenIdResult is printing on my front end:

```
claims:
auth_time: 1583265950
email_verified: true
iat: 1583266220
exp: 1583269820
phone_number: "+17777777777"
issuedAtTime: "2019-08-08T12:10:20Z"
expirationTime: "2019-08-08T13:10:20Z"
authTime: "2019-08-08T12:05:50Z"
```

Comment: If you experience what appears to be an "outage" in service, it's best to go to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to explain what's going wrong so they can at least collect this as a data point.

Comment: I'll point out that force refreshing a token on every request is almost certainly unnecessary.  The Firebase Auth SDK provides a way for you to listen in on token updates as they change. You'll find out right away if the token was refreshed with its normal automatic refresh cycle.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged